# Method of getting current location from IP address in Rails (geocoder and gmaps4rails gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I have an app which allows users to post Offers based on address they choose. I would like to add the option of saving the address based on the user's current location, determined by the IP address. I'm using the ruby Geocoder gem. This code will pass but it is not saving any address to the db. I'm not sure if it's an issue with my approach or if it is not working because of the development environment. I know that other features of Geocoder e.g. distance calculations don't work in development.

`current_location` is a boolean attribute of the Offer class

In the offers/_form View:

```
<div class="field"><br>
      <%= f.label :use_current_location? %>
      <%= f.check_box :current_location %>
</div>
```

In the OffersHelper:

```
def geocode_by_ip_address(offer)
    if :current_location
      offer.address = request.location.address
    end
end
```

In the Offer Model:

```
def geo_offer
  geocode_by_ip_address(offer)
end
```

For the purposes of the my map, gmaps4rails uses the following attributes:

```
def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.address}, #{self.city}, #{self.country}"
end
```

However the address is not saving (have checked using the console). Would appreciate any help! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if :current_location should be a symbol in your model if block. Calling the current_location method inside an object will resolve to the boolean value of current_location (provided your controller is saving it correctly) so change the code to:

```
def geocode_by_ip_address(offer)
    if current_location
      offer.address = request.location.address
    end
end
```

EDIT: Sorry just realised that this is in a helper and not the model, :current_location and current_location should both be undefined in your helper, you would need to pass that logic in (or I would put the if block inside the model and then call geocode_by_ip_address with the if block removed from there)

Comment: Thanks - part of the reason I used a helper is because the 'request' method belongs to the ActionView Module. Unfortunately it is still not working.

Comment: in that case my best advice would be to pepper the code with a few print statements to check that the request.location.address line is being run. That way you can check that the objects are behaving in the way they should (e.g. can't tell from this whether the controller is doing the right thing). once you isolate the line causing the problem, post back.