# How do I get the current location in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a gem that can print my current location to the console? For instance, my longitude or latitude or even my street address without inputting anything?

I read the Google-Maps-for-Rails and Geocoder docs and I have to provide input like longitude and latitude to get the address and so forth. I don't want the user to have to input anything, as soon as they run the program their location prints out, have it be street address or longitude and latitude

Does anyone know of a another way other then Geocoder or gmaps4rails to accomplish this?

Comment: You could get your external IP and geo-locate it using one of IP geo bases.

Comment: ok I will look into it, thanks a lot. Do you know if they deal with mobile as well, I guess gps

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934213/method-of-getting-current-location-from-ip-address-in-rails-geocoder-and-gmaps4?rq=1.

Comment: The question may fit here area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations when the site gets live.

Answer (score 1):

Using a gem like [Geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) you can geocode your external IP address although the result isn't very accurate. If you need GPS accurate results you can tap into your systems geolocation e.g. on Mac: https://github.com/robmathers/WhereAmI

Comment: yeah I tried that require 'geokit'
include GeoKit::Geocoders but got a error saying uninitialized constant MultiGeocoder (NameError) basically from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889599/rails-how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-string-address-and-put-it-on-google